# A deal in own country not by cheque or online only by cash

Tags: money-transfer, scams

I am a freelancer developer.  I just met a client who lived in USA. He has offered to hire me.

**Here's the catch.  The client said:** "I have been warned by my bank not to pay by cheque or make any online transfers. If you have a US representative, please get back to me with the address and phone number and I'll contact them and make payment". I gave him options to pay online or transfer but he refused all.

What you can suggest about this client> Is he telling the truth or he is a fake client?

**Things to note :**

- He told  me continuously: "I was warned by ...
- I have not done any work for him.
- He did  not talk about work at first. He has only   been asking about a representative number and address.
- I can communicate with him only on mail service.

Is it safe to give details to this client ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scam. Some one is trying to get details so that it can be used to either con you or your friend.

Don't give any details as it will be misused.

Comment: thanks man. this saved my money